# Reference Request on a good Linear Algebra book

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request

So I'm looking for a linear algebra book with a strong focus on proofs. It would be great if the book also uses concepts from regular abstract algebra like isomorphisms etc instead of dancing around it.

Note that a book of problems/solutions would also suffice and indeed possibly be more helpful.

Could someone suggest something?

EDIT : To be clear, This isnt exactly a duplicate question. I've already taken abstract algebra and I'm looking for a book which uses those concepts. Most of these links are for people who've never taken abstract algebra and want to start off with linear algebra

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/101994/book-reference-for-calculus-and-linear-algebra-engineer?rq=1 http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/173441/book-suggestion-for-linear-algebra-2?rq=1 http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/403654/first-course-in-linear-algebra-book-suggestions?rq=1 http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/461275/whats-a-good-book-on-advanced-linear-algebra?rq=1 http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/804716/very-good-linear-algebra-book?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1852334258) book? At my school, it is the text used for Advanced Linear Algebra. Where I go, Abstract Algebra is a prereq for it. I would imagine that book would be along the lines of what you're looking for. The book also has positive reviews from what I've seen.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend Advanced Linear Algebra by Steve Roman.  It has complete proofs for everything covered in the book.  Moreover, the proofs are very well written and are a pleasure to read.  It is written abstractly and assumes that you already know abstract algebra.